# blocking access to my apache server

Tags: apache, apache2

According to this site:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html

I need to use something like the script below to block access to my site for everyone except specific ip addresses:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from dev.example.com
```

It's not clear from that site, where I type this script.

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 as my development machine.

Comment: well, that was Freudian slip ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write exact IPs or it's starting part including ending dot under allow from and you are done.

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 192.168.1.1
Allow from 192.168.1.2
Allow from 10.0.
```

BTW, belongs to ServerFault.

Comment: Where do I type this, in the .htacess file?  Or is there a better place to type this?

Comment: @oshirowanen Yes, in .htaccess.